# Parallel Processing on Pyspark of around 1000 columns

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have a dataset of around 1500 columns and I am trying to replace zeros of all columns to Null. How can I do this efficiently in Pyspark?

I have tried using spark UDF but as the data is wide I am not able to process multiple columns in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a UDF. You can achieve it with  spark built in function `df.na.replace`. you can find more info about it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace). I put down a simple example achieving the same.

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F

 df = sc.parallelize([(1, 0, 5), (1,2, 0), (0,4, 5),  (1,7, 0), (0,0, 3),  
 (2,0, 5),  (2,3, 0)]).toDF(["a", "b", "c"])

        +---+---+---+
    |  a|  b|  c|
    +---+---+---+
    |  1|  0|  5|
    |  1|  2|  0|
    |  0|  4|  5|
    |  1|  7|  0|
    |  0|  0|  3|
    |  2|  0|  5|
    |  2|  3|  0|
    +---+---+---+

    df1=df.na.replace(0,None).show()

    +----+----+----+
    |   a|   b|   c|
    +----+----+----+
    |   1|null|   5|
    |   1|   2|null|
    |null|   4|   5|
    |   1|   7|null|
    |null|null|   3|
    |   2|null|   5|
    |   2|   3|null|
    +----+----+----+
```

To calculate distinct values in df

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df2=df1.agg(*(F.countDistinct(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns))

    df2.show()

    +---+---+---+
    |  a|  b|  c|
    +---+---+---+
    |  2|  4|  2|
    +---+---+---+
```

To calculate 99% and 1%.

```
    df1.summary('99%', '1%').show()

    +-------+---+---+---+
    |summary|  a|  b|  c|
    +-------+---+---+---+
    |    99%|  2|  7|  5|
    |     1%|  1|  2|  3|
    +-------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks. I probably gave a simplistic question. I am also looking at calculating basic stats that is outside of what df.summary() provides, such as count distinct values, 99%,1% etc on this.. Is there an efficient way to do this?